# How to properly eslint from root folder for node.js project

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have a project structure that looks like:

```
root/
    controllers/
    database/
    app.js
    server.js
    .eslintrc.json
    package.json
    etc...
```

I want to run eslint from command line to lint all .js files in root and subdirectories, but trying to use global patterns at this level is giving different errors:
If I try: `eslint ./**/*.js`, I start getting errors from `node_modules`, references from config files inside the modules..., which I assume means eslint is for some reason not ignoring the modules folder as it should by default.

The only way to get it working is by individually listing the files in the root and subdirectories, like:

`yarn run eslint controllers/** server.js app.js database/**`

Doing this works, but is not a very clean solution. Is this behavior expected? Must I necessarily put everything inside a `src` folder as usually done?

Comment: Have you checked out the `ignorePatterns` property in the `eslintrc` file? You can setup your rules and stuff and have a directory (`node_modules`) ignored. Check out this link: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code#ignorepatterns-in-config-files. Edit: You can also use an `.eslintignore` file

Comment: @ChrisGilardi yes, I also added "ignorePatterns": ["node_modules"] to the .eslintrc.json, unfortunately it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to eslint properly from root folder but in order to check all files at once, one option I could see is to put all the project files and folders (other than eslint.json, package*.json etc) in a new folder "src".

Post which project structure would be :-

```
root/
    src/
        controllers/
        database/
        app.js
        server.js
    .eslintrc.json
    package.json
    etc...
```

Then doing `npx eslint src`

Answer (score 0):

Something which worked for me was to use `.eslintignore` in the following way:

```
# Ignore everything recursively
*

# But not the .js files
!*.js

# Check subdirectories too
!*/

# Ignore specific folders
node_modules
```

Then run eslint as normal:  `npx eslint .`